# Bootstrapped curves and machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, python, finance

I am exploring machine learning models to employ for my use case as described below and would appreciate some expertise

Effectively I have bootstrapped bond prices to derive a zero coupon curve for the obligor however when comparing it with the Bloomberg curve for that same obligor my curve contains lots of volatility and outliers in comparison

I seek to use a ML model which would
Fit the bootstrapped curve to resemble that of Bloomberg.

Any ideas on what model can be used here to adapt my bootstrapped curve to the Bloomberg one?